# Differentiating between fair and biased coin:

Tags: confidence-interval

Let’s say that you have coin with heads probability of 50% and a coin with heads probability 55%. What is the number of coin tosses it will take you, in expectation, until you are 95% confident you have one or the other?

My efforts so far: trying to use hypothesis testing, however that would mean we want to have both $P(H_1|H_1) = \alpha$ and $P(H_0|H_0) = \alpha$, and I'm unsure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Consider $n$ tosses with $X$ heads.  What values of $X$ would lead you to choose one or the other hypotheses?  Check your intuition by justifying your answer probabilistically.   (This is where you need to know the distribution of $X$ under each hypothesis.)  Now, once you have a decision criterion, it's a simple matter of computing the decision error rates for any $n.$  Find the smallest $n$ where none of the relevant error rates exceed 100-95%=5%.